# want to make multiple if statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

how could I run this multiple If statement it only run the first if statement (as it is true) but I want the Programm to go for all the If statements step by step. Do check If statement for check13 as there is little difference in picking up the array.

```
Sub main_process_data()
   Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
   Dim check1 As Boolean, check5 As Boolean, check6 As Boolean, check7 As Boolean, check13 As Boolean

Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

check1 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn
check5 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 5").Value = xlOn
check6 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 6").Value = xlOn
check7 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 7").Value = xlOn
check13 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 13").Value = xlOn

If check1 Then
    s1.Range("C42").Value = s2.Range("B2").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C42").Value = vbNullString

If check5 Then
    s1.Range("C43").Value = s2.Range("B3").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C43").Value = vbNullString

If check6 Then
    s1.Range("C44").Value = s2.Range("B4").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C44").Value = vbNullString
    
If check7 Then
    s1.Range("C45").Value = s2.Range("B5").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C45").Value = vbNullString

If check13 Then
    s1.Range("C45").Value = s2.Range("B11").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C45").Value = vbNullString

End If
End If
End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Move each `End If` after its respective `Else`. So you should have `If...Else...End If`, then another `If...Else...End If`, and so on.

Comment: It works :) but what if i want to avoid this if statement multiple times?

Comment: Try a loop perhaps?

Comment: To clarify you could post example data and expected result.

Comment: @BigBen i am finding problem in making loop, could you help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a loop and `Offset`:

```
Dim checks As Variant
checks = Array(check1, check5, check6, check7, check13)

Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(checks) to Ubound(checks)
    If checks(i) Then
        s1.Range("C42").Offset(i).Value = s2.Range("B2").Offset(i).VAlue
    Else
        s1.Range("C42").Offset(i).Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next
```

Even better, skip creating the `check` variables:

```
Dim checkNums As Variant
checkNums = Array(1, 5, 6, 7, 13)

Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(checkNums) to Ubound(checkNums)
    If s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box " & checkNums(i)).Value = xlOn Then
        s1.Range("C42").Offset(i).Value = s2.Range("B2").Offset(i).Value
    Else
        s1.Range("C42").Offset(i).Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT**:

Since the ranges on `s2` are not contiguous, use two arrays:

```
Dim checkNums As Variant
checkNums = Array(1, 5, 6, 7, 13)

With s2
    Dim ranges As Variant
    ranges = Array(.Range("B2"), _
                   .Range("B3"), _
                   .Range("B4"), _
                   .Range("B5"), _
                   .Range("B11"))
End With


Dim i As Long
For i = Lbound(checkNums) to Ubound(checkNums)
    If s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box " & checkNums(i)).Value = xlOn Then
        s1.Range("C42").Offset(i).Value = ranges(i).Value
    Else
        s1.Range("C42").Offset(i).Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Great. If for some reason you end up having non-contiguous ranges on `s1`, you can add a third array for them.

Answer (score 1):

To run each if one by one it should be like this:

```
Sub main_process_data()
   Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
   Dim check1 As Boolean, check5 As Boolean, check6 As Boolean, check7 As Boolean, check13 As Boolean

Set s1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set s2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

check1 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 1").Value = xlOn
check5 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 5").Value = xlOn
check6 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 6").Value = xlOn
check7 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 7").Value = xlOn
check13 = s2.CHECKBOXES("Check Box 13").Value = xlOn

If check1 Then
    s1.Range("C42").Value = s2.Range("B2").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C42").Value = vbNullString
End If

If check5 Then
    s1.Range("C43").Value = s2.Range("B3").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C43").Value = vbNullString
End If

If check6 Then
    s1.Range("C44").Value = s2.Range("B4").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C44").Value = vbNullString
End If

If check7 Then
    s1.Range("C45").Value = s2.Range("B5").Value
Else
    s1.Range("C45").Value = vbNullString
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a Select-Case (switch-case in C#) instead of If-Else, as a form of pattern matching. See: [Select Case statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement)